# Linq to entities with EF in an specific relational model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

If someone could give me an idea with it, it would really appreciate it.
How can I get all Users (not related entities) that have records in the Connections Table and belong to a Company (Table) with an id predefined (let's say CompanyId=1), using Entity framework and linq to entities. I have defined my entities classes with foreign keys and navigation(entities) properties. I would rather lambda expressions methods.

This is the relational model:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this?

```
var users = dbContext.Users.
             Where(usr => usr.UserTeams.Any(
                                   usrTeam => usrTeam.Team.CompanyId == 1)) 
             Where(usr => usr.Connections.Any());
```

Comment: Thanks, it was what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So if you defined your foreign key constraints and your navigational properties correctly this should work:

```
                var users = db.Companies.Include("TeamId")
                                        .Include("UserId")
                                        .Include("ConnectionId")
                                        .Select(x=>x.Teams.Users.Username)
.where(x=>x.Teams.Users.Connections!=null && x.CompanyId==1).tolist();
```